# Why is this PySide2 build failing to find a generated C++ wrapper?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside

I'm trying to build the latest release of PySide2 on MacOs Sierra 10.12.2 (16C67) with python 3.6. As of now, the build invoked with

```
python3 setup.py build
```

is failing with the following error: (I have substituted my name out of my home directory...)

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/myusername/pythonpackage/pyside-setup/pyside3_build/py3.6-qt5.8.0-64bit-release/pyside2/PySide2/QtCore/PySide2/QtCore/qabstractstate_wrapper.cpp'
```

I am using Qt 5.8 as installed by homebrew.

I have looked through the build log and cannot find where/if that file is generated, as I am not familiar with the binding generation. Using PyQt is not an option, as its license is not applicable to my application.

Why is this source missing, and what can I do to make the build succeed?

PySide2 was installed from this repo: git://code.qt.io/pyside/pyside-setup.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I stated the issue in the actual question: The PySide2 README states that it supports Qt 5.5 and 5.6. I was trying to use 5.8.

I solved my problem by using an old homebrew qt installed via:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/fdfc724dd532345f5c6cdf47dc43e99654e6a5fd/Formula/qt5.rb
brew install ./qt5.rb
```

followed by the build invocation, and it worked.